# Android - Use WebView to evaluate a javascript string and return the value

Tags: android, webview, android-scripting

Given that scripting is not natively supported in Android and wrapping libraries like  javax.script.ScriptEngine  into your app will make it too large, is it possible to send a javascript string to an invisible WebView and have it evaluate the string and return you the results (another string)?

I want to go this route because I want to save all my scripts to disk so my app can remain small.

**Edit**

I need Java code to evaluate javascript strings not the other way around. **addJavascriptInterface()** doesn't help.

Comment: How is the javascript going to going to see your program in order to act upon it? Just executing scripts in a vacuum isn't going to do much good.

Answer (score 6):

Can it be done? Yes, via `addJavascriptInterface()` and sending the browser a `javascript:` URL, akin to a bookmarklet.

A far simpler answer, one that will use much less memory and will execute much faster, is to not use Javascript.

Comment: I don't think **addJavascriptInterface()** will return a String value

Comment: addJavascriptInterface() lets Javascript code call Java code, and Javascript should be able to pass a String parameter to said Java code.