# Send gps coordinates to server in XML

Tags: android, gps

I am making an app in which i want to send gps coordinates like latitude and longitude to server in xml .. Can anybody help me how to do this .. Any help will be appreciated ...
Thanks..

Answer (score 1):

Google is really your friend on this one. Stackoverflow is more ment for programming issues, not tutorials on how to do something, noone will write the code for you.

What have you tried earlier?

Similar question [How to send GPS data from android to a website?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2707501/how-to-send-gps-data-from-android-to-a-website)

[Obtaining users location](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/obtaining-user-location.html)

Send to server: 
[Android (Java) Simple Send and receive with Server - Fast Setup Challenge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/983761/android-java-simple-send-and-recieve-with-server-fast-setup-challenge)

[How to send a data to a web server from Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5666109/how-to-send-a-data-in-web-server-from-android)

Soap:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3112426/best-soap-tutorials

[Android WSDL/SOAP service client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1484122/android-wsdl-soap-service-client)

[How to call a SOAP web service on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/297586/how-to-call-soap-web-service-with-android)

Answer (score 0):

One way I can think of is to initiate a POST request via HTTP using a URL like:

```
http://server.example.com/postgps
```

(Assume `server.example.com` is the server to send the data to.)
The request body would then contain XML data.

The question, however, is too vague for us to help further.

Answer (score 0):

What does your server accept as an interface? GML is a standard XML grammar for geographic information. You can simplify it by using GML Simple Features Profile. If you want something even easier, you might try GeoURI.